# Is a question about Paul Hoffman's Left hand of God on topic here?

Tags: support, scope

As per the title, I'd like to ask a question about [The Left Hand of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Left_Hand_of_God_(novel)).

I've found only [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64837/help-me-identify-a-fantasy-book-please) about it, but it's just a story identification question, so I'm not sure I can take the existence of that question as a positive answer to my question here on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short, yes.** The book itself seems to be a bit of a rag-bag of various medieval fantasy tropes plus a soupçon of dystopia, alternative worlds and a self-insert hero with overt super powers (to whit, the ability to determine how an enemy will attack before they do so).

> “I can read what you’re going to do,” said Cale. “The instant you
> start to move. It’s just a fraction faster than before my injury, but
> it’s always enough. No one can read what I’m going to do, no matter
> how quick or experienced they are.”

Note also that the book is marketed as "[Fantasy and Supernatural](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B003ZUXX88/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1)" by the publisher.

Comment: Thank you very much. In case you're interested, I've posted the question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240051/why-does-paul-hoffman-refer-to-jesus-as-the-guy-in-the-womb-of-the-whale).

Comment: Atium burning ?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Something like that. It's not really that explicit how his powers work, other than that they do, that they appear to be the result of a random head-trauma-related accident and that they a) can't be replicated and b) are sufficiently conspicuous that they merit extensive experimentation by the authorities.